# .NET app.manifest - should I set the assemblyIdentity?

Tags: .net, manifest

If I understand this right, the <assembly manifestVersion="1.0" part in an app.manifest is left alone.

But what about <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>? Should that be changed to match the name and version number of my application?

thanks - dave

Comment: It plays no role in a .NET assembly so changing it makes little sense.

Comment: @HansPassant - thank you